# Podman: ERRO[0000] The storage 'driver' option must be set in /etc/containers/storage.conf

Tags: containers, podman, arch

I'm on Manjaro, trying Podman and getting this error when I use any podman command:

```
ERRO[0000] The storage 'driver' option must be set in /etc/containers/storage.conf, guarantee proper operation.
```

How can I solve that? Tks.

Comment: What version of `podman` is installed? Are you running `podman` as `root`, or as another user?

Comment: @larsks I'm using podman 3.0.1, and with root or without root it gives the same message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem, try setting the option in the config file like described in the man page [here](https://www.mankier.com/1/podman#Global_Options---storage-opt=value). For me changing `driver = ""` to `driver = "fuse-overlayfs"` did the trick.